# Custom 2013 SharePoint Workflow Not Starting

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

I designed a custom workflow in SharePoint designer to collect multiple people's approval. It is supposed to initiate with some emails once it begins or with manual start. However once a new item is added, nothing happens. This is the current workflow: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DlTl.jpg.

Comment: if nothing happens the first question is: do you use a System Account to test it? Normally domain account don't start workflows. Try another user instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can narrow down your issue as following:

1. Have you published this workflow to SharePoint?

[image]

2. Have you ticked the “Start workflow automatically when an item is created” in the workflow settings?

[image]

3. If the workflow works well when you start the workflow manually? Make sure you don't use System account to create the item in SharePoint.
4. In the list view, is there a workflow column with the stage name? if so, you can click the link to check if there is error message for the workflow.